# Messages App keeps merging two people who are in different countries but same number?

Tags: google-messages, oppo

So this is literally one in a million, but I have two different contacts in two different countries who incredibly have the same last 6 digits of the phone number i.e.:

Contact 1 in Australia: +614 123 123
Contact 2 in New Zealand: +6421 123 123

The messages app keeps merging the conversation trails and replying on it it is unclear who will receive the message. E.g. I just replied on it and it went to the wrong person (embaressingly).

This happened after upgrading from an old crappy Android Go phone to a brand new Android 10.0 phone and cloning all the information over. However even if I delete both contacts and recreate them with thoes numbers, it still merges the conversation thread!

How can I separate the message threads?

Comment: Interesting +1. Couple of things to try 1. Add one contact to a separate account and of course add that account to your device 2. Try a different messaging app 3. Instead of country code try using 0 (if permitted) //1 and 3 are guesses (no logic)

Comment: .4 clear cache messaging app before trying another app. Next backup your messages (using apps from Play Store) and clear data too to rule out messaging app problems